# Clear the background color of pushed view controller

Tags: ios

I want to clear the background color of push viewcontroller.
When I add a subview background color set to clear works fine but not working when I try to push a view controller on navigation controller.
[image]

Comment: Please, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25287714/3052059

Answer (score 0):

your controller looks like presenting view controller, so may be you should present it, but not to push? i had the same problem and now using this way to present view controller:

```
+ (void)showWithParent:(UIViewController *)parentController {
    static SomeViewController *singleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        singleton = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeViewControllerID"];
    });
    [parentController presentViewController:singleton animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**parentController** in my case is a some view controller pushed in navigationViewController